# Python Dictionary Formatting Query

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is a small basic function to create a dictionary:

```
def Professor(name,salary,course):
    ProfDict = {"Name":name,"Salary":salary,"Course":course}
    return (ProfDict)
```

I want to return the dictionary in a nice format such as:

Name: Fred Smith; Department: History; Salary: £30000

I cannot find much about dictionary formatting,
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary isn't formatted, as it is just a data structure. What you want is to construct a string using the data stored in the dictionary.

```
def Professor(name,salary,course):
    ProfDict = {"Name":name,"Salary":salary,"Course":course}
    return "Name: {0[Name]}; Salary: {0[Salary]}; Course: {0[Course]}".format(ProfDict)
```

Comment: Thanks that's a nice way of doing it, I will remember this

Comment: I actually tried it with Python 2.7 and without the 0 in the placeholders, and got the error:

`IndexError: tuple index out of range`

With the 0s in the placeholders it works on 2.7

Comment: I removed that last part. Most of my work is still in Python 2.6, so I forgot how exactly omitting the field name works.

Comment: You always need the `0` if you're using the attribute more than once. Omitting the indices assumes you are going by order (`0`, `1`, ...)

Comment: Yeah, that was the part I forgot. In my quick test to get the indexing syntax right, I only tested with a single key (`'Name: {[Name]}'.format({"Name": "Me"})`).

Answer (score 2):

Pass the dictionary as **kwargs to the string's `format` function:

```
def Professor(name, salary, course):
    prof_dict = {"Name": name,"Salary": salary,"Course": course}
    return prof_dict

some_prof = Professor(...)
nice_string = "Name: {Name}; Department: {Course}; Salary: {Salary}".format(
    **some_prof)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this You want:

```
def Professor(name,salary,course):
ProfDict = {"Name":name,"Salary":salary,"Course":course}
return (ProfDict)

temp = Professor("Fred Smith",30000,"History")
print "Name:",temp["Name"] + "; Department:",temp["Course"] + "; Salary: " + str(temp["Salary"])
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, don't return the dictionary in parentheses. To print it, do like so:

```
ProfDict = Professor("Dr. Bob", 100000, "Intro to Medical Coding")
for key, value in ProfDict.items():
    print key, ':', 'value, ";",
```

You can or course use any additional string formatting to make it look however you want.